# finding a symbol and parsing only the text that has a symbol

Tags: python, parsing, search

Hey I'm new to python and I'm working on a project that has a license system and i need it to on parse the license key and not anything else and i need it to print only the license key here is my code that i put to gather for this post

```
valid = "-"


string = "(0): xxx-xxx-xxx"


if (valid.find(string) == None):
    print("String has no symbols")

else:
    print("String has a symbol")
```

here is a example of what i want license key to look like

Note#

the correct license key = **parsed_license**

the incorrect license key = **unparsed_license**

```
parsed_license = "xxx-xxx-xxx"

unparsed_license = "(0): xxx-xxx-xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
valid = '-'
string = '(0): xxx-xxx-xxx'

def get_valid_string(string, valid):
    return [x for x in string.split(' ') if valid in x][0]
```

in the code above I suppose your string always is going to be as you wrote before, so I'm filtering the invalid input, creating a single element array with the correct string and returning its element, this code will work if your input string has one and only one valid string, otherwise you will lose some, the solution is to remove the index at the return statement and return the valid strings array